catalyst package plot MST
I'm just wondering how to plot a MST, just like when using flowsom, but do it using the catalyst package instead. I have followed the catalyst tutorial on bioconductor and just finished the clustering bit. It would be nice to be able to visualise the clustering using a MST but I am not sure how to do it...
Thanks a lot for helping
Here's the code I tried for clustering using catalyst package:
sce <- cluster(sce, features = "type", 
               xdim = 10, ydim = 10, maxK = 20, 
               verbose = FALSE, seed = 1)

Then I tried the following to plot a MST:
fsom <- metadata(sce)$SOM
PlotStars(fsom, view = "MST", backgroundValues = fsom$metaclustering)

However I got the following:
Error in UpdateFlowSOM(fsom) : fsom should be a FlowSOM object.
I'm not sure how to make this work now...
